# Standard form submit render page, but passing data to server by $.post() not render page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My problem is that this code is display "blablabla" when I push 'submit':

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php if (isset($_POST["text"])):{
    echo $_POST["text"];
}else: ?>
    <form action="" method="post" id="testform">
        <input type="text" value="blablabla" name="text"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
<?php endif ?>
</body>
</html>
```

but this second code continue to display the form even after clicking on the button and does not show "blablabla":

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function (){
        $('#testbtn').click(function() {
            $.post('',{text:'blablabla'});
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php if (isset($_POST["text"])):
    echo $_POST["text"];
else: ?>
    <form action="" method="post" id="testform">
        <input type="button" id="testbtn"/>
    </form>
<?php endif ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Why?

Comment: $.post() doesn't reload the current page and since you don't rewrite the body with the result of post, nothing is changed.

Comment: How can I reload the current page after posting data to server using php or JavaScript?

Comment: window.location = "http://websi.te/" in success function but why would you do that if you can do it in pure php..

Comment: I add the success function to post function() {
                location.reload();
            });
but this did not help me. I see only button, but not "blablabla".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic, if we do an ajax post, just send the content we want to show inside the body, else show the entire page like if it was a normal form submit. The success callback inside the ajax call, will replace the body with innerHTML

```
<?php

function getBody() {
       if (isset($_POST['text'])) {
          // normally I would htmlspecialchars() this variable to disallow HTML injection
          echo $_POST['text'];
       }
}

if (isset($_POST['ajax'])) {
       getBody();
       exit();
}

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function (){
        $('#testbtn').click(function() {
            $.post('',{text:'blablabla', 'ajax':1}, function(bodyData) {
               document.body.innerHTML = bodyData;
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php if (isset($_POST["text"])):
    getBody();
else: ?>
    <form action="" method="post" id="testform">
        <input type="button" id="testbtn"/>
    </form>
<?php endif ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had not thought about the 'data' variable of success post function! =) In your example it is 'bodyData'.

Answer (score -1):

give the page url in post

```
$.post(window.location, {tetx: 'blablabla'}, success: function(data) {
      alert('successful.the response from server is' + data);
    });
```